# Insert Data From One Table to Another Table with default values

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query works fine but I have a different requirement.

My requirement is as follows.
I have table1 and table2, table1 contains 5 columns and table2 contains 3 columns. Now, we need to pull data from table2 and insert into table1. Here in table2 contains only 3 columns and table1 contains 5 columns. So the rest should insert with some default values.

Could someone help me how to write a query for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the default values 1 and 2 here

```
Insert into table1(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
select col1,col2,col3,1,2 from table2
```

Comment: Madhivanan, I tried the same as (insert into table1 (Code,Country) select CountryCode,test from table2). Here test is default value. When I tried to compile this I got issue as - SQL Error (207) : Invalid column name 'test'.

Comment: It means that you do not have that column in table2

Comment: @BSaiYaswanthReddy - Try this  
`INSERT INTO table1
            (Code,Country,def_col)
SELECT Country,Code,'test'
FROM   table2`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply ignore default value colums in Insert statements.

```
Insert into table1(col1,col2,col3)
select col1,col2,col3 from table2
```

It'll have default values in col4 & 5.